# What is wrong with my php mail contact form?

Tags: php, html, phpmailer

I'm using a template for a contact form for my website. The problem is, when I test it on my server I cannot send a message. It will only give me my error message and not send. Did something happen when I translated the original send text to German?

I've tried debugging the vars. I've also tried to `echo` some string inputs.

This is the html code:

```
                        <form id="contact-form" action="mail.php" method="post">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
                                <label class="sr-only">Name</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" name="name" placeholder="Name" >
                                <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
                                <label class="sr-only">Email</label>
                                <input type="email" class="form-control input-lg" name="email" placeholder="Email" >
                                <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-12 form-group">
                                <label class="sr-only">Betreff</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" name="subject" placeholder="Betreff" >
                                <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-12 form-group">
                                <textarea class="form-control input-lg" rows="7" name="message" placeholder="Nachricht"></textarea>
                                <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-round btn-dark">Senden</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
```

PHP:

```
<?php

//  POST GET.
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    // Form Felder GET.
    $name = strip_tags(trim($_POST["name"]));
            $name = str_replace(array("\r","\n"),array(" "," "),$name);
    $email = filter_var(trim($_POST["email"]), FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
    $subject = trim($_POST["betreff"]);
    $message = trim($_POST["nachricht"]);

    // Check ob Daten an den mailer.
    if ( empty($name) OR empty($subject) OR empty($message) OR !filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        // 400 (bad request) und raus.
        http_response_code(400);
        echo "Bitte füllen Sie alle Felder aus.";
        exit;
    }

    // Empfaenger.
    $recipient = "info@test.de";

    // Betreff.
    $subject = "Neue Anfrage von $name";

    // Inhalt.
    $email_content = "Name: $name\n";
    $email_content .= "Email: $email\n\n";
    $email_content .= "Betreff: $subject\n\n";
    $email_content .= "Nachricht:\n$message\n";

    // Header.
    $email_headers = "Von: $name <$email>";

    // Senden.
    if (mail($recipient, $subject, $email_content, $email_headers)) {
        // 200 (okay).
        http_response_code(200);
        echo "Vielen Dank! Deine Nachricht wurde versendet.";
    } else {
        // 500 (internal server error).
        http_response_code(500);
        echo "Oops! Hier ist ein Fehler passiert, deine Nachricht konnte nicht gesendet werden.";
    }

} else {
    // 403 (forbidden).
    http_response_code(403);
    echo "Es gibt Probleme mit deiner Anfrage, bitte versuche es ernuet.";
}

?>
```

Comment: What do you intent with the `Von` header in the mail message? Even if your email application shows "Von" for the from-field, the actual header in the message should be in English: `"From: $name <$email>"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your input name for subject is in English in your form, but in your php file is in German

Choosing the same lang for all your code can to avoid confussions

Change name attributes to german to make it work

```
<input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" name="betreff" placeholder="Betreff" >
<textarea class="form-control input-lg" rows="7" name="nachricht" placeholder="Nachricht">
</textarea>
```

Comment: I would translate it all to English instead of German (i.e. `$subject = trim($_POST["subject"]);` in the PHP code and same for the message). Code (and also comments) are usually only in English.